# What's the largest count of accepted answers in a single day ever achieved on SFF.SE by a single user?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, site-statistics

While reading Meta.SO answers related to reaching 200 rep, rep caps and Epic/Legendary badges, I caught an expression

> "Earn 9 accepted answers and zero upvotes"

as one of the means of reaching 200.

While that example is clearly extreme to the point of absurdity, it got me intensely curious: **what was the maximum amount of answers by one user accepted withing a single day?** (I'm not really interested in who the user is, just the count - basically as a benchmark of what it should be possible to strive for :)

If any Stack Exchange Data Explorer expert would be kind enough to show how to get the following answer, it would be much appreciated (I'd prefer to learn to fish to being given the fish, of course :)

Comment: "Earn 9 accepted answers and zero upvotes" is also incorrect, as you would need 14 accepted answers to break 200. Unless the rep value for accepted answers was 22.22222222222 (repeating) at some point.

Comment: @Xantex - most likely I'm misremembering meta post details :)

Comment: Might be worth re-asking this again in a day or so.

Comment: @Valorum Holy flaming mother of obscenities. How the hell did you manage that? Have all your socks been out accepting answers? Did you use the Force on dozens of OPs?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I got sick of looking at unaccepted answers and went a'proddin'.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I want someone to mash [this cross-site tool](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/355774/cross-site-query-template) with [this search](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/60982/most-accepted-answers-in-a-day). Would you mind asking in chat for me?

Comment: @Valorum http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507405/most-accepted-answers-in-one-day-across-network

Comment: @KutuluMike - Interesting stuff. I'm intrigued why the number on Productivity:SE is so low.

Comment: The user links in the query should now go to the correct user (in most cases.. can't swear to mathoverflow working.)

Answer (score 9):

### On SFF, 43 (Valorum), followed by 16 (you), 14 (you), 13 (Valorum).

On Christmas Eve 2015, you not only hit the repcap but more than doubled that with your **SIXTEEN** accepted answers. This superhuman feat, which I observed myself at the time, was the best ever on this site until just a couple of days ago when Valorum absolutely slaughtered all competition by leaving hundreds of comments nagging OPs for acceptances and successfully gaining **FORTY-THREE** acceptances in one day, mainly on old answers. From [the query in Gilles's answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/60982/most-accepted-answers-in-a-day):

[image: Data.SE query]

Your churning out of TFA answers in December left everyone else biting your dust, until Valorum went on an OP-nagging spree. You also had some good days back in 2012, and Valorum has had a few more good days this year. Honourable mention to BESW for a spate of acceptances early in 2014.

Comment: @amaranth - Was that intentional? 49 accepted answers from nearly as many users in a low-traffic period, most of which are months old....

Comment: @Obie2.0 He prodded loads of OPs in comments to accept his answers.

Comment: Wow, he must have asked on hundreds of questions, to get 49 accepted....

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Well, I had been afraid to ask people to accept my answers because I thought they would downvote, but maybe I should go look at some of my old answers. Not that I will beat Valorum, but I could get some more rep. :)

Comment: @Obie2.0 Well ... leaving a huge number of comments like that is kinda frowned upon, and automatically alerts the mods. I recommend doing just a few at a time, perhaps for answers you felt were particularly good or OPs who've been particularly bad at accepting answers.

Comment: OK, sure.......

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I only prodded those that I felt were pretty much definitive (e.g. where there's a direct quote or reference that specifically answers the question asked). Those answers that are pure supposition or those that are in contention with other answers I've left alone.

Answer (score 7):

https://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/60982/most-accepted-answers-in-a-day

```
DVK                 5   2012-01-24 
Slytherincess       4   2011-12-08 
DVK                 4   2012-01-09 
DVK                 4   2012-01-19 
DampeS8N            3   2011-01-12 
DampeS8N            3   2011-01-16 
Mike Scott          3   2011-01-19 
JustinM             3   2011-01-19 
DVK                 3   2011-04-28 
HorusKol            3   2011-09-26 
Jeff                3   2011-10-14 
TangoOversway       3   2011-11-04 
Jeff                3   2011-11-19 
DVK                 3   2011-11-26 
DVK                 3   2011-12-02 
DVK                 3   2012-01-04 
Slytherincess       3   2012-01-09 
HorusKol            3   2012-01-14 
DVK                 3   2012-01-17 
Slytherincess       3   2012-01-19 
DVK                 3   2012-01-21 
gnovice             3   2012-01-22 
TangoOversway       3   2012-01-24 
Tony Meyer          3   2012-02-01
```

(more with ≤2)

P.S. The top few rows on a few sites:

```
Jon Skeet           30  2011-09-28   SO
womble              13  2011-07-05   SF
Evan Anderson       12  2009-07-09   SF
ooshro              12  2011-02-24   SF
ooshro              12  2011-02-28   SF
agent86             12  2011-12-12   Gaming
agent86             12  2011-12-17   Gaming
caliban             11  2009-09-18   SU
Majenko             11  2011-04-04   SU
Paul                11  2011-12-06   SU
David Mitra         11  2012-01-19   Math
Arturo Magidin      10  2011-10-23   Math
Rinzwind             8  2011-05-08   Ubuntu
Gilles               8  2011-05-13   Unix
Gilles               8  2011-07-13   Unix
Gilles               8  2011-07-19   Unix
AviD                 8  2010-11-15   Security
Thomas Pornin        5  2011-06-16   Security
```

Comment: I wanna be Jon Skeet's sock puppet account!

Comment: Huh! Interesting. I didn't know! :)